# How to include source code in ant ear

Tags: java, ant, ear

I'm building an ear file using ANT build.xml and need to include *.java* files in my ear package created. Any pointers?

Below is the war section from my `build.xml`

```
    <target name="war" depends="compile">
        <war destfile="${dist}/${ant.project.name}.war" webxml="${warbasepath}/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
          <lib dir="${lib}" />
          <classes dir="${build}"/>
          <fileset dir="${warbasepath}/WebContent" excludes="**/*.class **/*.jar" /> 
        </war>
    </target>
```

Comment: you never include the extra content.

Comment: @Vivek Why would you want to include the source code in your executable? Sourcecode can be bundled separately.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [EAR task manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ear.html). It is just an extension of the JAR task, so you can include whatever you like. ​

You can include arbitrary filesets:

```
<ear destfile="${build.dir}/myapp.ear" appxml="${src.dir}/metadata/application.xml">
    <fileset dir="${build.dir}" includes="*.jar,*.war"/>
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
</ear>
```

However an EAR should be just a container for wars and ejb jars, so you probably should add your source code rather in those.